# Webdriver opens multiple window, When Script is executing. How to resolve this?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, java

When I am calling method from another class at that time, WebDriver opens multiple Firefox window.

This is main class:

```
package selenium2Pack;

import java.sql.Date;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import selenium2Pack.loginPOI;

public class CounselorEducation {

    static FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    loginPOI xpath;

    @Test
    public void AddEducation() throws InterruptedException{

        loginPOI.CounselorLogin();
        Thread.sleep(10000);
        //Click on Education tab
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/nav/ul/li[2]/a")).click();
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        //Click on AddNew button
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div[1]/a/i")).click();

    }

}
```

This is calling method:

```
package selenium2Pack;

import javax.swing.text.Document;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class loginPOI {

    static FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    static String firstName = "html/body/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/form/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/input";
    String Email,LastName,BrowseButton,Username,Password,ContactNo,Gender,DOB,Country,State,City,Street,Address,Marital_status,Logout,EducationTab;
    static String RegisterURl = "http://192.163.222.186/~puzzlelife/development/#/register";
    static String LoginURL = "http://192.163.222.186/~puzzlelife/development/#/login";
    public  void main() throws InterruptedException{
        String firstName = "html/body/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/form/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/input";
        String LastName = "html/body/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/form/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/input";
        String BrowseButton = "html/body/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/form/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/input[1]";
        String Email = "html/body/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/form/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/input";
        String Username = "html/body/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/form/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/input";
        String Password = "html/body/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/form/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/input";
        String ContactNo = "html/body/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/form/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/input";
        String Gender = "html/body/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/form/div[1]/div[4]/div[2]/select";
        String DOB = "html/body/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/form/div[1]/div[5]/div[1]/div/span/span";
        String Country = "html/body/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/form/div[1]/div[5]/div[1]/div/span/span";
        String State = "html/body/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/form/div[1]/div[6]/div[1]/select";
        String City = "html/body/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/form/div[1]/div[6]/div[2]/select";
        String Street = "html/body/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/form/div[1]/div[7]/div[1]/input";
        String Address = "html/body/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/form/div[1]/div[7]/div[2]/textarea";
        String Marital_status = "html/body/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/form/div[1]/div[8]/div/select";
        String Logout = "html/body/div/header/div/div[3]/div/a[2]";
        String EducationTab = "html/body/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/nav/ul/li[2]/a";
        }

    public static void CounselorLogin() throws InterruptedException{

        driver.get(LoginURL);
        Thread.sleep(15000);
        driver.findElement(By.id("username")).sendKeys("arun");
        driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("arun");
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        WebElement submit =driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/form/button"));
        submit.click();
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        String  CurrentURL = driver.getCurrentUrl();
        if(LoginURL.equals(CurrentURL))
            System.out.println( "Un-Successful to login");
            else
            System.out.println("Successful to login");
        Thread.sleep(10000);
        }

    public static void Logout() throws InterruptedException{

        //Click on Logout Button
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div/header/div/div[3]/div/a[2]")).click();

        Thread.sleep(5000);

        //Check text on page
        if(driver.getPageSource().contains("Login"))

            System.out.println("Successfully Logout");
    else

        System.out.println("Un-Successfully Logout");

    }

    public static void DOB(){


    }

}
```

Comment: which script are you executing?

Comment: public void AddEducation() throws InterruptedException{
  
  loginPOI.CounselorLogin();
  Thread.sleep(10000);
  //Click on Education tab
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/nav/ul/li[2]/a")).click();
  Thread.sleep(5000);
  //Click on AddNew button
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div[1]/a/i")).click();
  
 }

Comment: I am executing my code, my login code is in another class. I am calling login method by creating object

Comment: @BhushanPatil, please edit your question and add the formatted code.

Comment: Try to initialize the driver in one class. Here you using 'loginPOI' and 'CounselorEducation'.

Answer (score 5):

Your are initializing the Firefox Browser in both the classes

```
static FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

i.e `public class loginPOI` and `public class CounselorEducation`

Hence you are getting multiple browsers opened.
Initialize the driver only in one class.

Whenever you call a method of a class its Static Variable also get initialized.
So First the driver is getting initialized in `public class CounselorEducation` in that class you are again calling the  `loginPOI.CounselorLogin();` which again invokes it's own static driver. This is why you are getting multiple windows.